# Whitespace with multiline string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, multiline

I have a whitespace issue with multiline strings.

I have something similar to this in my code where I'm generating some SQL.

```
def generate_sql
   <<-EOQ
      UPDATE page
         SET view_count = 10;
   EOQ
end
```

But then my SQL indention is all messed up, which I don't really want.

```
"       UPDATE page\n          SET view_count = 10;\n"
```

I could do

```
    def generate_sql
<<-EOQ
UPDATE page
   SET view_count = 10;
EOQ
    end
```

Which outputs exactly what I want

```
"UPDATE page\n   SET view_count = 10;\n"
```

But then my code indention is all messed up, which I don't really want.

Any suggestions on how best to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: I didn't say it won't be presented to users

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby 2.3.0 solves this nicely with the [squiggly heredoc](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/multiline-strings-ruby-2-3-0-the-squiggly-heredoc). Note the difference of the tilde/hyphen between examples.

```
hyphen_heredoc = <<-MULTILINE_STRING
                    One line
                    Second line
                      Indented two spaces
                    MULTILINE_STRING

squiggly_heredoc = <<~MULTILINE_STRING_WITH_TILDE
                      One line
                      Second line
                        Indented two spaces
                      MULTILINE_STRING_WITH_TILDE

2.3.0 :001 > puts hyphen_heredoc
                      One line
                      Second line
                        Indented two spaces
2.3.0 :002 > puts squiggly_heredoc
One line
Second line
  Indented two spaces
```

With the squiggly heredoc, The indentation of the **least-indented** line will be removed from each line of the content.

Answer (score 7):

There are libraries like [`ruby-dedent`](https://github.com/cespare/ruby-dedent) that let you do

```
require 'dedent'

def generate_sql
   <<-EOQ.dedent
      UPDATE page
         SET view_count = 10;
   EOQ
end
```

Which results in

```
"UPDATE page\n   SET view_count = 10;"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ought to do it:

```
def generate_sql
  <<-EOQ.gsub("\n", " ").strip
    UPDATE page
      SET ...
  EOQ
end
```

Though in this case, your DB will ignore the whitespace, so it may not be worth going to the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

This takes a little more space (and is perhaps less pretty) but works well:

```
def generate_sql
   text = <<-EOQ
      UPDATE page
         SET view_count = 10;
   EOQ
   text.gsub(/^#{text.match(/^\s*/)[0]}/, '')
end
```

gives

```
"UPDATE page\n   SET view_count = 10;\n"
```